# How can I get the button text to display my cell text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create an asp.net GridView and I bind some simple data. Some strings have newlines in `\n`

This displays as a new line when I add the right css to the table cell : `white-space:pre-wrap;`

But then I cycle through my GridView and add a button in each cell like so:

```
    protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.CssClass = "Button";
                btn.Text = cell.Text;
                cell.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }
```

The text added to the button isn't the same format. All the `&nbsp;` have become visible and the newlines `\n` aren't working. At first I thought I needed to just reapply the `pre-wrap` css but I tried it and it didn't affect anything. Also, I think the problem is further up the chain in the `btn.Text = cell.Text` line because of the `&nbsp;` becoming visible.

Does button control text not behave like the default cell text? Maybe I can replace buttons with labels or something...

Comment: why do you need a `Button` ? a `Button` will translate to a `<input>` html tag which can't contain html tags

Comment: Because I want the cell to react with clicks etc. (NO JAVASCRIPT) - if I change it to any input control (e.g. label, dropdownlist) will I suffer the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `Button` type which will result in the following HTML

```html
    <input type="button" value="Press here" />
```

the `input` html tag can't contains HTML but just text. If you want to add html inside your button you can use a `LinkButton` which will result in the following HTML

```html
    <a href="...">
        Press here
    </a>
```

and the `a` tag can contain any HTML code or CSS style.

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
{
    LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
    btn.CssClass = "Button";
    btn.Text = cell.Text;
    cell.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for alternative controls. Labels don't have an onclick event so I was getting a little worried but yeah, I'll try links I guess! Although it'll take some extra faffing to make the entire cell clickable and not just the text.